# Website with/without user login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Howdy,
I'd like to create a website with c# and ASP.NET. This Website should feature a front end which is accessable by all visitors - and then I'd like to create a backend which is only accessibly after the user logged in ... however I'm facing a couple problems since this is my first web project in C# and in general.

I think I have to create at least 3 classes:

Page - ( every page should inherit this page )
holds if the page should be an open or closed page
Loginpage
Membership Page
Checks if the user is really logged in and which user it is.

I have no clue if this is the right way to do it - and how I should do. I would be really grateful 4 help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the MembershipProvider.  ASP.NET comes with some pre-rolled controls for logging users in and out, as well as several mechanisms for checking whether a user is logged in and what roles they have.  You can secure resources programmatically by checking on what roles the current user has and make decisions in code, or in the web config by requiring specific user names and/or roles to access a given resource (such as a page).

Here's an intro link to get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Once you're done getting a general feel for what the MembershipProvider is, here's a video to walk you through setting up a SqlMembershipProvider:

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/) sample is so useful.
[image: Here]
Review it.

> Project Description MyWSAT aka ASP.NET
>   WSAT is a WebForms based website
>   Starter Kit for the ASP.NET Membership
>   Provider. It is a feature rich
>   application that takes care of all the
>   basics to save you time. Use it as a
>   template to start your websites. 
>   MyWSAT v3.5 PROJECT OVERVIEW:
>
> MyWSAT aka ASP.NET WSAT is a WebForms
>   based Website Starter Kit for the
>   ASP.NET Membership Provider with Forms
>   Authentication. It provides you with
>   all the security features required for
>   a site out of the box so you start
>   focusing on building your pages. It
>   allows you to manage membership users
>   online once your site is deployed. It
>   features complete administrative
>   back-end functionality and designed to
>   manage users, as well as admin pages
>   for users to manage their own user
>   data.
>
> MyWSAT works with the default
>   membership provider database tables to
>   manage membership users, roles and
>   profiles and uses a few specially
>   crafted stored procedures for
>   efficient paging of any amount of
>   records... and a few more things as
>   you will see. It consists of simple
>   procedural programming with neatly
>   organized and commented code. The
>   programming methodology is geared
>   toward the beginning developer to help
>   quickly gain some practical every day
>   development knowledge. MyWSAT has been
>   used in many production environments
>   (personal and enterprise) and is
>   reliable and secure. A perfect starter
>   kit for your next Blog, CMS,
>   E-commerce or any project that
>   requires security and user management.
>
> Tip: You can save this website as a
>   template and use it to create new
>   sites based on it.
>
> TECHNOLOGY USED:
>
> This application was created in Visual
>   Web Developer 2008 Express (works with
>   2005 and 2010) with SQL Server 2008
>   Express , .NET version 3.5 and C#.NET.
>   This release is not available in
>   VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ASP.NET, there is a lot of existing infrastructure here you can take advantage of. Look into:

- Microsoft ASP.NET Membership API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx
- Login Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx
- Forms authentication

Microsoft has pretty much fully solved/written all of this for you. Now you might still prefer to avoid their implementation for whatever reason, but it's still worth looking into.